# Conditional job offer

Tags: job-offer

In the case a conditional job offer is denied, is the employer required to inform the potential employee of this decision and if so how long should it take for them to get back to you??

Comment: Please share more details. As it is now, this question has very little context and is difficult to answer and unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: The answer is probably "no", they are not required to. Perhaps you actually want to ask how long to wait before following up with such an "offer" (which is not actually an offer). There are good questions to search for which discuss this case.

Answer (score 4):

There is no explicit limit on how long background checks and other conditional "gates" can take.

You have to decide how long you are willing to wait for them before taking another job instead.

Note that until a firm, unconditional offer has been put on paper and you have accepted that, ***you have not been hired.*** You should not give notice on your current job, or stop job hunting, until that firm offer reached you.

Answer (score 0):

As keshlam says, a conditional job offer is *not a job offer*. It's a statement that the company *might* be going to make you a job offer. Until an offer is unconditional you should continue to pursue other leads, go to other interviews, as before. You should not resign your current job.

When a company makes you a conditional offer, ask them to tell you when they expect to make it unconditional. If it gets to that time you should ask them for an update on progress, and ask them again when they expect to make an unconditional offer.

Meanwhile, if any of the other leads you are pursuing pans out, and you get an offer of a different job you would like, immediately contact the first company and tell them you have another job offer. Tell them the deadline on that offer, and ask them to expedite their processing. Eventually of course you might have to decide whether you are going to take the firm job offer you have now, or wait for the other one that might come. That's something only you can decide, and depends on many factors.